# save image by name from camera into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, save, image

I'm sorry I'm a newbie in here. I have a method `startCamera` like this:

```
public void startCamera() 
{

        Cursor c=helper.getById(almagId);
        c.moveToFirst();    
        fileName = helper.getKdStore(c)+ waktu + ".jpg";         
        Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA", "Starting camera on the phone...");
        //String fileName = "testphoto.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image capture by camera");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //return intent;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
       if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) 
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA","Picture taken!!!");
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

            }
        }
    }
```

and then I have the method `insertImage` in Dbhelper like this

```
public void insertPicture(String image1,String image2,String image3){

    //waktu = new Date().toString();
    ContentValues im = new ContentValues();
    //im.put("kdstore", kdstore);
    im.put("image1", image1);
    im.put("image2", image2);
    im.put("image3", image3);

    System.out.println();
    getWritableDatabase().insert("image", "name", im);
}
```

I want to save pictures by name in sqlite, so that I can retrieve them back later.

Answer (score 2):

As Jox Traex said there is no need to store image in database.it will be easy if you store only path of image.and then retrieve image from the same path only. you can refer some sample related code

```
  MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(path_img) {
        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return "image/jpg";
        }
    };
    attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
    attachmentPart.setFileName("image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you people getting your idea... **WHY** would you insert the image into the database? Just store a link to where the file is in the database...

While databases offer the blob option, you definitely don't want to do that all the time.. it would be messy. Explore other alternatives and **STOP** being so black and white about a solution.